# using Get request with URLConnection

Tags: java, url, networking, network-programming, ioexception

I am currently writing program to communicate with a device in my network, and the following code is what I have so far, it passed authentication and can get the webpage from the device, however i couldnt get the GET request to work, when I run the code below, i get the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.100.222:80
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

when I input data on the webpage, its equivalent of going http://l192.168.xxx.xxx/2?A=3&p=1&X=1234, and from tcpflow, it does `GET /2?A=4&p=1&X=1234 HTTP/1.1`, 
I tried creating a new url connection with http://192.168.xxx.xxx/2?A=3&p=1&X=1234, and it worked, but i have multiple input options and i dont want to create a new connection for each of them, how can I do the equivalent while staying connected? or what I did wrong in the code?

thanks in advance.

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.xxx.xxx");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write("Get /2?A=4&p=1&X=1234 HTTP1.1");
    out.close();        
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String decodedString;
    while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(decodedString);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: It is working perfectly for me without any issue. I tried with localhost and not in network. Also I didn't used `Authenticator`

Comment: is there any possible issue u can think of?

Comment: Remove `Authenticator` and check

Comment: the device requires authentication, without it, it wont connect at all
perhaps i should do another `Authenticator` before `out.write`?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to create a new connection for each of them

Don't worry about that. `HttpURLConnection` does connection pooling under the hood. Just use your actual URLs, don't try to out-think Java.

Comment: is there something relink the url? something like `url = http://192.168.xxx.xxx/2?A=3&p=1&X=1234` ?

Comment: @3v01 Please restate your question in standard English. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: is there a way to redefine the url in `url`?

Comment: @3v01 Again I don't know what you're talking about, but it doesn't matter. HTTP connection pooling is done for you automatically behind the scenes. You don't have to worry about reusing/redefining *anything.*